# mpsc channels stucking at the receiver

Tags: rust, channel, rust-tokio, mpsc

```
use std::sync::Arc;

use tokio::sync::mpsc;

async fn student(id : i32,tx : Arc<mpsc::Sender<String>>) {
    println!("student {} is getting their hw.",id);
    tx.send(format!("student {}'s hw !",id)).await.unwrap();
}

async fn teacher(mut rc : mpsc::Receiver<String>) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut homeworks = Vec::new();
    while let Some(hw) = rc.recv().await {
        println!("{hw}");
        homeworks.push(hw);
    }
    homeworks
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx,rc): (mpsc::Sender<String>, mpsc::Receiver<String>) = mpsc::channel(100);
    let ch_arc: Arc<mpsc::Sender<String>> = Arc::new(tx);
    
    for i in 0..10 {
        tokio::task::spawn(student(i,ch_arc.clone()));
    }
    let hws = teacher(rc).await;
    println!("{:?}",hws);
}
```

I am currently learning channels in Rust and now I have faced some issues. the issue is that when I am running the line  `teacher(rc).await`;
 code is getting stuck at that point I don't have any clue why this is happening, but one thing that I observed while solving this issue is that when I am spawning multiple tasks I am getting stuck in the loop but when I am only doing one spawn at `student(i,ch_arc.clone());` line it is working fine.
can anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this loop here:

```rust
while let Some(hw) = rc.recv().await {
```

`recv` will only return `None` when the sender is dropped, hanging up the channel. The sender is in an `Arc`, so it will be dropped when all `Arc`s have been dropped.

There's 10 `Arc`s inside the `student` futures, which are dropped when each of those finish. They don't have anything to wait on, so that happens quickly. However, there is one `Arc` left over. `ch_arc` isn't dropped until the end of `main`, which happens after calling `teacher`. So `ch_arc` is never dropped.

You can fix this by manually dropping `ch_arc`:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx, rc): (mpsc::Sender<String>, mpsc::Receiver<String>) = mpsc::channel(100);
    let ch_arc: Arc<mpsc::Sender<String>> = Arc::new(tx);

    for i in 0..10 {
        tokio::task::spawn(student(i, ch_arc.clone()));
    }

    drop(ch_arc);

    let hws = teacher(rc).await;
    println!("{:?}", hws);
}
```

Or by putting `ch_arc` inside a block. This block returns `rc` since you need to use `rc` later.

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let rc = {
        let (tx, rc): (mpsc::Sender<String>, mpsc::Receiver<String>) = mpsc::channel(100);
        let ch_arc: Arc<mpsc::Sender<String>> = Arc::new(tx);

        for i in 0..10 {
            tokio::task::spawn(student(i, ch_arc.clone()));
        }
        rc
    };

    let hws = teacher(rc).await;
    println!("{:?}", hws);
}
```

Comment: Idk, I tried changing the loop to do 1 instead of 10 and it still hung.

Comment: idk I am not able to write code in the comment but what I wanna say is when i am running this loop inside a spawned task I am not getting stuck in the loop

Comment: tokio::task::spawn(async move {
            for i in 0..10 {
                student(i, ch_arc.clone()).await;
            }
        }
    );

Comment: `move` means the async block now owns `ch_arc`, and it'll drop it when the async block finishes.